# SQL Query - Insert values from two columns in another table into one column

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-insert

Can anyone please help me with an SQL query which will allow me to populate the real_name column in table 1 with values from both first_name and second_name columns in table 2 by referencing the usernames.

TABLE 1

| audit_username | real_name |
| --- | --- |
| AHolland |  |
| THardy |  |
| LGentle |  |
| BGreen |  |

TABLE 2

| second_name | first_name | username |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Holland | Andrew | AHolland |
| Hardy | Tom | THardy |
| Gentle | Lauren | LGentle |
| Green | Barry | BGreen |

Comment: Is table1 empty? Or how to determine names from second column match row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear to me whether you just want to execute a query or to really change the data in table1.
If you want the query only:

```
SELECT
  t1.audit_username,
  CONCAT(t2.first_name, ' ', t2.second_name) AS real_name
FROM
  table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.audit_username = t2.username;
```

If you want to change the data:

```
UPDATE 
  table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 
    ON (t1.audit_username = t2.username)
SET 
  t1.real_name = CONCAT(t2.first_name, ' ', t2.second_name);
```

See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/kA0F6hsP) this will work correctly.

Note: Take care to use the correct syntax to update the table! The syntax provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77077873/18794826) is invalid for a `MySQL` DB.

I recommend to read some documentations, for example [this one](https://mysqlcode.com/mysql-update-join/) about the correct syntax for such update commands.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
UPDATE TABLE1 T1 SET 
real_name=((SELECT CONCAT(firstname, ' ',  lastname) FROM TABLE2 WHERE username = T1.audit_username ))
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert values from two columns in one table into a single column in another table using SQL, you can use the INSERT INTO statement along with a SELECT query to retrieve the values from the source table. Here's a general syntax for such an operation:

Example-

INSERT INTO destination_table (destination_column)
SELECT source_column1 || ' ' || source_column2
FROM source_table;

Comment: INSERT is not applicable here as the questioner wishes to update existing rows in Table1